# How do exchange services provide forked coins to their customers for free?

Tags: blockchain-fork

I know we can get forked coins by donating to ICO teams but I don't think the exchange services donte to them.
So I really consider how to get forked coins for free

Comment: What exchange is providing forked coins for free? What forked coins? When? What do ICOs have to do with that?

Comment: I mean some exchange services gave their customers some forked coins such as bitcoin cash for free, so I wonder how did the exchange services give their customers bitcoin cash for free?

Comment: Well, in the case of Bitcoin Cash, the coins were not issued as ICOs, they were created as a fork of the original Bitcoin blockchain. So at the moment of the fork everybody owning bitcoins owned the same amount of Bitcoin Cash.

If some exchange somewhere decided to give theirs for free, the exchange didn't need to do anything to get their Bitcoin Cash units.

Comment: I see so what's the situation that some exchange services didn't give me bitcoin cash even though I had bitcoins when the hard fork occurred.

Comment: 1: Why someone you didn't say the name didn't give you something? You'll have to ask to them.
2: If you have Bitcoins when they created Bitcoin Cash, you have Bitcoin Cash units. Install the client and spend them. Exchanges doesn't even need to exist.

Comment: So if I have bitcoin cash in my wallet, can I send that via bitcoin-cli?

Comment: I think you need to use Bitcoin Cash software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forked coins have nothing to do with ICOs.

You get forked coins by holding the coin that was forked from before the fork. After the fork, you will have the same amount of the original coin and the same amount of the forked coin. Exchanges who hold coins that then get forked will then also get the same amount of forked coins, as does anyone else. Whether they give you access to these forked coins is up to the exchange.

It may be technically difficult for them to do so so an exchange might not give you access to the forked coins. They may wish to keep the coins to themselves instead of giving free money to their customers. Without asking the exchange themselves, you cannot know why they didn't give you the forked coins.